# Flipped sign in fixed effects model

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I'm estimating the effect of health (0=poor; 1=good) on labor force participation (0=non-participant; 1=participant). So I expect a positive coefficient on health. This holds for OLS, Pooled OLS, random effects and population-averaged estimates. However, when I estimate a FE model, the sign gets flipped. This obtains whether or not I include controls. Any idea why this sign flip?

Comment: The fixed effect estimator is known as the within estimator because its' estimation is only based upon within group variation. Something to check... how many observations do you have where someone switches from good to poor health (or vice versa)?  Something weird going on with that subset of the population?

Comment: For a binary dependent variable, you would need to use a differnt kind of model as the dependent variable is not continuous. Look at (panel) probit models...

Comment: @helix123 as a general assertion your statement is plain wrong. OLS works fine in this case, where partial effects are the main interest

Answer (score 1):

One reason is related to what Matthew had remarked in his comment. Given that fixed effects only uses the within variation, this requires that there is variation in labor market participation and health status. However, I would imagine that for many individuals in your sample health status changes relatively little but employment status will change even less often.

In this sense, the fixed effects estimator kicks out observations which have either employment equal to 1 (or 0) for all time periods, and/or health status equal to some value for all time periods. This leaves those people for whom health status changes. Now depending on the context, a negative may or may not make sense.
For instance, if you are in the United States where health care is very costly and you are not insured, some people may have to take up work in order to pay for their medication. Probably this is a far fetched case but something you might want to explore in your data.

Comment: It's still bizarre though right? Going individual by individual, I'd imagine they're more likely to be in the labor force when healthy and out of the labor force when sick? A lower health status is associated with lower labor force participation hence the coefficient is positive? It really seems like something weird is going on either with the analysis or the data.

Comment: Agreed. I would probably also expect a coding error in the data, mistreatment of missing values or the like, From a theoretical point of view, the finding makes no sense. So clearly something must be off but without further information about the data it is hard to say what it is exactly.